# Creating LVM partition on SD card fails with "device not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-netbook-remix, lvm

I'm trying to create a single LVM volume on my SD card, using Ubuntu Netbook Remix. The SD card is at `/dev/mmcblk0`. So far, I've used `fdisk` to create a partition (type `8e - Linux LVM`) on the device. The partiton is `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. However, when I run

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

I only get this response:

```
Device /dev/mmcblk0p1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

As the [Ubuntu Guide](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) suggests, I've tried looking at my [`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`](http://iki.fi/ilari.kajaste/dist/lvm.conf.txt), but the filter seems to be ok - the problem remains even when the default option is enabled.

```
# By default we accept every block device:
filter = [ "a/.*/" ]
# Only devices beginning with "mmcblk":
# filter = [ "a|/dev/mmcblk.*|", "r/.*/" ]
```

I assume the problem is somewhere within the LVM configuration, since when I run `sudo vgscan -vv` with the default "accept every block device" configuration, it lists many devices being scanned - however not the `/dev/mmcblk` devices. When using the more restrictive filter, it scans no devices.

My complete [`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` is available online](http://iki.fi/ilari.kajaste/dist/lvm.conf.txt) for inspection.

I've tried reading multiple guides about setting up LVM ([1](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/),[2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall),[3](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/02/how-to-create-linux-lvm-in-3-minutes/)), but none of them seem to be of help with this issue.

**Any ideas what is going wrong? How would I troubleshoot this issue further?**

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=483686

Comment: @derobert: Right, so it's actually a bug with lvm2 - thanks for the link! It seems this is `"Fixed in lvm2-2.02.45-4.fc11"`. Now I'll just have to see how to get that version on Ubuntu Netbook Remix...

Comment: There is a workaround in the bug (or, rather, two): either change the name to something lvm will understand via udev or `types = [ "mmc", 16 ]`... I'd post as an answer, but I have no way to test either of those.

Comment: @derobert: Looking at the man page, udev seemed quite a hassle, since I'm not familiar with it. However, editing `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` to include the `types` definition worked! So feel free to post is as an answer to get the reputation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bug report 483686 on Redhat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=483686) (link provided by user [derobert](https://superuser.com/users/1735/derobert)) this is actually caused by a bug in lvm2. *"lvm2 doesn't understand mmcblk devs."*

The bug is reported "`Fixed in lvm2-2.02.45-4.fc11 / lvm2-2.02.45-4.fc12`" on 2009-04-17. So what remains to solve the issue is getting the fixed version of lvm2 on Ubuntu Netbook Remix.

In the meantime, there's an easy workaround. Adding a `types` definition to the `devices` section of `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` fixed the issue:

```
# Hackaround to get LVM to understand mmcblk0 as a device,
# bug report at bugzilla.redhat-com/show_bug.cgi?id=483686
types = [ "mmc", 16 ]
```